# How add class current/active to the link which is pointing to the current page?

Tags: jquery

I have written this line of jQuery code to compare the current url and link url for assigning the class active to it but get last line of urls in c and d variables as undefined.

Why is this happening?

```js
var a=window.location.href;
var d=a+$("a.date sort_by_time").attr('href');
var c=a+$("a.date sort_by_some").attr('href');
console.log(c);
console.log(d);
if (a==c)  {
  $('.date sort_by_time').addClass('active');
}
if (a==d) {
  $('.date sort_by_some').addClass('active');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="date">
  <p>sorting:&nbsp;</p>
  <a href="?sortby=some" class="sort_by_some"><i class="icon-star-empty"></i>by some</a>
  <a href="?sortby=date" class="sort_by_time">by time<i class="icon-calendar"></i></a>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure what you are trying to achieve here. I am not sure where the 'a' variable is coming from. Have you not copied all the code onto your post?

Is this what you want? If not, please provide more information.

https://jsfiddle.net/at3e1u84/

```
   var d = $(".date > .sort_by_time").attr('href');
   var c = $(".date > .sort_by_some").attr('href');
   console.log(c);
   console.log(d);
```

UPDATE:

I have made it a big more complicated than your original idea by adding some regex. I'll explain why:

If the link is www.example.com/?sortby=some:

```
a = www.example.com/?sortby=some
c = www.example.com/?sortby=some?sortby=some
d = www.example.com/?sortby=some?sortby=time
```

a can never be equal to either c or d because it's comparing to itself + an addition.

That's why I used regex to get the '?...' part of the url and compare it to the href's.

I hope this will be the solution to your problem.

https://jsfiddle.net/at3e1u84/4/

```
  let regex = /\?sort.*/;
  let matches = (window.location.href).match(regex);
  var a = matches ? matches[0] : null;

  var d = $(".date > .sort_by_time").attr('href');
  var c = $(".date > .sort_by_some").attr('href');
  console.log(a);
  console.log(c);
  console.log(d);
  console.log(window.location.href)
  if (a == c) {
    $('.date > .sort_by_time').addClass('active');
  }
  if (a == d) {
    $('.date > .sort_by_some').addClass('active');
  }
```

Comment: Thnx for the fast reply i do want to compare with current url ut got undefined at the endings of $c $d variables in console log

Comment: (index):48 https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/undefined
(index):49 https://fiddle.jshell.net/_display/undefined

Comment: Not sure what you mean with those fiddle links.
Check out my update

Comment: finally got it .Thnx Wouter.

Answer (score 0):

Here you go with a solution

```js
var a=window.location.href;
var d = a + $("a.sort_by_time").attr('href');
var c = a + $("a.sort_by_some").attr('href');
console.log(c);
console.log(d);
if (a==c)  {
  $('.date sort_by_time').addClass('active');
}
if (a==d) {
  $('.date sort_by_some').addClass('active');
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="date">
  <p>sorting:&nbsp;</p>
  <a href="?sortby=some" class="sort_by_some">
    <i class="icon-star-empty"></i>by some
  </a>
  <a href="?sortby=date" class="sort_by_time">by time
    <i class="icon-calendar"></i>
  </a>
</span>
```

Hope this will help you.